# I am trying to run this vba any suggestions

Tags: vba

I am  rookie in this any suggestions for running it

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim LU As Double, HG As String, CN As Double
LU = Range("B1").Value
HG = Range("G1").Value
    If HG = A Then
     Select Case LU
    Case Is = 1
        CN = 77
    Case Is = 3
        CN = 67
    Case Is = 4
        CN = 30
    Case Is = 5
        CN = 39
    Case Is = 6
        CN = 49
    Case Is = 7
        CN = 77
    Case Is = 12
        CN = 98
    Case Else
        CN = 0
    End Select
ElseIf HG = B Then
   Select Case LU
    Case Is = 1
        CN = 85
    Case Is = 3
        CN = 78
    Case Is = 4
        CN = 55
    Case Is = 5
        CN = 61
    Case Is = 6
        CN = 62
    Case Is = 7
        CN = 86
    Case Is = 12
        CN = 98
    Case Else
        CN = 0
    End Select
ElseIf HG = C Then
   Select Case LU
    Case Is = 1
        CN = 90
    Case Is = 3
        CN = 85
    Case Is = 4
        CN = 70
    Case Is = 5
        CN = 74
    Case Is = 6
        CN = 74
    Case Is = 7
        CN = 91
    Case Is = 12
        CN = 98
    Case Else
        CN = 0
    End Select
ElseIf HG = D Then
   Select Case LU
    Case Is = 1
       CN = 92
    Case Is = 3
        CN = 89
   Case Is = 4
        CN = 77
   Case Is = 5
        CN = 80
    Case Is = 6
        CN = 85
    Case Is = 7
        CN = 94
    Case Is = 12
        CN = 98
    Case Else
        CN = 0
    End Select
ElseIf HG = NA Then
        CN = 98
End If

Range("G1").Value = CN
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your variable declarations it appears that you want the code to run based on cell values.

```
Dim LU As Double, HG As String, CN As Double
LU = Range("B1").Value
HG = Range("G1").Value
    If HG = A Then
    Select Case LU
```

I'm guessing that you haven't used the Option Explicit directive at the top of your module so VBA is treating A as a variable instead of a string.  I think you want this:

```
Dim LU As Double, HG As String, CN As Double
LU = Range("B1").Value
HG = Range("G1").Value
    If HG = "A" Then
     Select Case LU
```

If that's right then you should probably take care to use Trim$ when you pull the range value (unless you do not want the code to match on A followed by spaces).

You also want to turn on Option Explicit.  It will help to trap these types of errors in your code.